# How to detect KRACK attack?

Tags: wifi, wpa2, krack

I want to create a honeypot that will detect KRACK attacks. Is there any way to detect that kind of attack, are there any traces, any information that is stored in log files (syslog for example) that tells: "You are under KRACK attack"?

Comment: top google hit for your title as search term: https://github.com/securingsam/krackdetector

Comment: @schroeder - Thank You for that hint. It doesn't appear in my Google search.

Answer (score 3):

A WiFi card in monitor mode will (given the right circumstances, id est in range of the client, the AP and the attacker) pick up the repeated third step of the handshake.

A filter rule could find such packets and trigger an alert.

There’s nothing in (usually configured) logs or otherwise persistent to the attack itself.

Comment: APs should also be able to alert when frames with the zero-key encrypted are received. This would indicate vulnerable Android clients (but might happen without attack)

Comment: Yes, but that’d be a firmware feature that’s not going to be commonplace. And it would only detect parts of the attack.

Comment: Is there a smartphone app that i can install for iPhone (tm) that will monitor and alert me?

Comment: @AndyzSmith not as far as I know. And if there is, it’s only for jailbroken iPhones, which brings in a load of other problems. That’s because you do not have access to the hardware as directly as you need within the API.

Comment: Any smartphone? Code for Arduino with wifi shield?

Comment: @SmokeDispenser Thank You. I used krackdetector from schroeder hint. It works fine for me.

Comment: Ok to be clear, use Android smartphone, BCM3340 wifi chipset,, reaver APK, bcmon APK, and custom script.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a straight answer but can help a lot in your case, I believe.
Here is a script that can detect if your WIFI AP is vulnerable to HRACK :

[This script tests if APs are affected by CVE-2017-13082 (KRACK attack)](https://github.com/vanhoefm/krackattacks-test-ap-ft)

The script was made by one of the original authors of KRACK.

Comment: Thank You, I know that script and I have been using it, but it don't anwser my needs.